# Renaming files if they contain 2 strings with batch

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have a file "codes.txt" containing one code per line.

I am trying to search and rename in a folder all files containing a code in their name, and also another string :

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=*" %%b in (codes.txt) do  (

// If file names in folder contain %%b and "foo", rename to %%b.'string'
// If file names in folder contain %%b and "foo2", rename %%b.'string2'

)
```

Thank you

Comment: What will the codes be in `codes.txt` also will foo be before, or after the name of `%%b`? or both?

Comment: Codes will be like this, pure numbers : 3614271992932. foo can be before or after %%b, depending on filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file `codes contains:

```
1234
5678
```

and your dir has a files called:

```
foo1234.txt
1234ABCfoo.txt
5678.txt
```

Then this script will do:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (codes.txt) do (
   for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *%%i* ^| findstr "foo"') do echo %%a
)
```

First it loops through codes.txt, using newlines as delimeters. Then it will do a dir on files containing the codes, and a `findstr` for foo anywhere in the name. Using the above files it will then echo the only 2 matches found:

```
foo1234.txt
1234ABCfoo.txt
```

It will not match `5678.txt` because it did not have `foo` anywhere in the name.

Obviously you would need to change the `echo` part in my script to the command you want to achieve.